# Show that Cayley Transforms extends to a homeomorphism

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry

I'm reading Complex Made Simple by David C. Ulrich and there says that

> The Cayley transform $\phi : \mathbb{D} \to \Pi^+$ extends to a homeomorphism of $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ and $\overline{\Pi^+}$.

How can I prove this? And why it doesn't extend to a conformal equivalence?